# Displaying Password Meter Strength Level

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

```
enter code here
```

```js
function passwordScore(password)
var score = 0;
if (!pass)
    return score;
//
var letters = new Object();
for (var i=0; i<pass.length; i++) {
    letters[pass[i]] = (letters[pass[i]] || 0) + 1;
    score += 5.0 / letters[pass[i]];
}
//Checking the variations that have been entered in the password meter.
var variations = {
    Digitals: /\d/.test(pass),
    LowerCaseLetters: /[a-z]/.test(pass),
    UpperCaseLetters: /[A-Z]/.test(pass),
    NonSpaceWords: /\W/.test(pass),
}

varitationCount = 0;
for (var check in varitations) {
    variationCount += (variations[check] == true) ? 1 : 0;
}
score += (variationCount - 1) * 10;

return parseInt(score);
//Checking the password strength score with the name of the strength level.
function checkPasswordStrength(pass) {
    var score = passwordScore(pass);
    if (score > 80)
        return "Very Strong";
    if (score > 60)
        return "Strong";
    if (score > 40)
        return "Good";
    if (score > 20)
        return "Weak";
    if (score > 0)
        return "Very Weak";

    return "";
}
```

```css
/* The font type, background colour and the margin settings for the body tag*/
body {
    font-family: "Calibri (Body)";
    background-color: #006699;
    margin: 0;
}
/* The font size, padding, margin, text align and background colour settings for the h1 tag*/
h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #cccc99;
}
/* The padding, width and the margin settings for the div tag*/
div {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/* The width settings for the myInput function*/
#myInput {
    width: 100%;
}
.Strength{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Password Meter</title>
    <!--The CSS link tag for the StyleSheet.css file.-->
    <link type="text/css" href="./StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--The script tag for HideorDisplay.js file.-->
    <script src="HideorDisplay.js"></script>
    <!--The script tag for PasswordMeter.js file.-->
    <script src="PasswordMeter.js"></script>
    <!--The script tag for PasswordStrengthLevel.js file.-->
    <script src="PasswordStrengthLevel.js"></script>
    <!--The script tag for Suggestions.js file.-->
    <script src="Suggestions.js"></script>
    <!--The script tag for PasswordIntegrity.js file.-->
    <script src="PasswordIntegrityFacts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--The Password Meter header tag.-->
    <h1> Password Meter</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="password" id="myInput" class="input_1, Password" onkeyup="checkPasswordStrength()"><br><br>
        <div class="Strength" id="StrengthLevel" text="Strength Level"></div>
        <div class="Strength" id="StrengthScore" text="Strength Score (0)"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="passwordVisible()"> Hidden or Visible
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am currently creating **password strength meters in visual studio in ASP.net**. The main page is html linking to style sheets and JavaScript files.

The strength level code is coded in JavaScript linked to a HTML page. The requirements of the strength level along with the score is
`0 = very weak`, `20 = weak`, `40 = good`, `60 = strong` and `80 = very strong`.

Currently I am having problems getting the strength level to appear when the program is running because when I am typing the password, nothing is appearing. I don't know how to resolve this.

I have tried to link to the div class id but nothing is happening.

I have looked at a few examples that are written in JavaScript but they are complex to understand.
*Can anyone please provide suggestions into resolving this problem or provide a example into structuring the code and linking the function to HTML page?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your JS? Is it even called? You should provide some (relevant!) code

Comment: Please provide some relevant code. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: HtML Code<input type="password" id="myInput" class="input_1, Password" onkeyup="checkPasswordStrength()"><br><br>
        <div class="Strength" id="StrengthLevel" text="Strength Level"></div>
        <div class="Strength" id="StrengthScore" text="Strength Score (0)"></div>

Comment: JavsScript Codefunction passwordScore(password)
var score = 0;
if (!pass)
    return score;
//
var letters = new Object();
for (var i=0; i<pass.length; i++) {
    letters[pass[i]] = (letters[pass[i]] || 0) + 1;
    score += 5.0 / letters[pass[i]];
}
//Checking the variations that have been entered in the password meter.
var variations = {
    Digitals: /\d/.test(pass),
    LowerCaseLetters: /[a-z]/.test(pass),
    UpperCaseLetters: /[A-Z]/.test(pass),
    NonSpaceWords: /\W/.test(pass),
}

Comment: varitationCount = 0;
for (var check in varitations) {
    variationCount += (variations[check] == true) ? 1 : 0;
}
score += (variationCount - 1) * 10;

return parseInt(score);
//Checking the password strength score with the name of the strength level.
function checkPasswordStrength(pass) {
    var score = passwordScore(pass);
    if (score > 80)
        return "Very Strong";
    if (score > 60)
        return "Strong";
    if (score > 40)
        return "Good";
    if (score > 20)
        return "Weak";
    if (score > 0)
        return "Very Weak";

    return "";
}

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("input").on("keyup",function(){
var pass = $(this).val();
var strength = 1;
var arr = [/.{5,}/, /[a-z]+/, /[0-9]+/, /[A-Z]+/];
jQuery.map(arr, function(regexp) {
  if(pass.match(regexp))
     strength++;
});
console.log(strength==1?"very Weak":strength==2?"Weak":strength==3?"medium":strength==4?"good":"very good");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id called `password` to the input tag and remove the inline event handler eg.

```
<input type="password" id="password" class="input_1 Password"><div>
```

Made a few slight changes to the Password Meter js file

```
 function scorePassword(pass) {
    var score = 0;
    if (!pass) {
        return score;
    }

    var letters = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
        letters[pass[i]] = (letters[pass[i]] || 0) + 1;
        score += 5.0 / letters[pass[i]];
    }

    var variations = {
        digitals: /\d/.test(pass),
        lowerCaseLetters: /[a-z]/.test(pass),
        upperCaseLetters: /[A-Z]/.test(pass),
        nonSpaceWords: /\W/.test(pass),
    }

    variationCount = 0;
    for (var check in variations) {
        variationCount += (variations[check] == true) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    score += (variationCount - 1) * 10;

    return parseInt(score);
}

function checkPassStrength(pass) {
    var score = scorePassword(pass);

    if (score > 80) {
        return "Very Strong";
    } else if (score > 60) {
        return "Strong";
    } else if (score > 40) {
        return "Good";
    } else if (score > 20) {
        return "Weak";
    } else if (score <= 10) {
        return "Very Weak";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Add another function to the Password Meter js file to display the values from above.

```
var password = document.getElementById("password");
password.onkeyup = function () {

    var pass = this.value;
    var strengthLevel = document.getElementById("StrengthLevel");
    var strengthScore = document.getElementById("StrengthScore");

    strengthLevel.innerHTML = checkPassStrength(pass);
    strengthScore.innerHTML = scorePassword(pass);
}
```

To toggle the input element (toggle password visibility) add an id called `passwordVisibility` to the checkbox then add another function to the Password Meter js file

```
var passwordVisibility = document.getElementById("passwordVisibility");
passwordVisibility.onclick = function() {
    var togglePasswordVisibility = document.getElementById("password");
    if (togglePasswordVisibility.type === "password") {
        togglePasswordVisibility.type = "text";
    } else {
        togglePasswordVisibility.type = "password";
    }
}
```